# Statistical average as the number of items averaged increases, regardless of their value

Tags: statistics, business-intelligence

A statistics question (I think) for calculating potential profits as I increase the number of products I sell:

If I have 5 individual products that I know from historical data will sell an average of 10 each per day, can I count on that average staying the same if I increase my product number to 10 items? Or should I assume more items will force my average down, all else being equal?

What about if the number of products increases to 50, or 500? Statistically speaking, what should happen to the average number of times sold per day, per item...stay the same, or get smaller?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because its better suited to stats.stackexchange.com

Comment: This isn't even a statistics question; it's a business question. It can only be answered by knowing what the products are and how they interact with each other - for example, if they're competing or complementary goods. In any case, it's completely off topic for Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0):

Economics question actually. Remember supply and demand are an X graph. Meaning as you increase a certain number of products your revenue rises until so many have been sold (supply overflow) that they are no longer in demand. Costs for warehousing and such become so expensive that you lose money just as radically as you made it. Every company struggles with finding the happy medium. Less Supply -> Everyone wants, More Supply -> Can find on clearance. 
 As for a statistically speaking answer, you do NOT have historical data that supports newer products being involved. Therefore, if you attempted to run this through a naive bayes algorithm it would give some funky answer because of no historic info.